# How to increment a counter variable in flask app every time request comes to a specific route?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a scenario in which I want to increment every time a request comes to the /train route.
I have tried this using the global approach in which I declared a counter  Variable globally and I'm deploying this application on google app engine.

My confusion is my app is running 24/7 on google cloud then After some time, my counter variable resets to 1 even declaring globally.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key='abc'
global classifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 500,criterion='entropy',random_state=0,warm_start=True)
global ovr
global counter
counter = 0
ovr = OneVsRestClassifier(classifier)
selected_features = []


@app.route('/train', methods=['POST'])
def train():
    global counter
    counter = counter + 1
    data = flask.request.json
    dataset = to_DataFrame_(data)
    if checking_nan_values(dataset):
        dataset = filling_NaNs(dataset)
    dataset = encoding_target_feature(dataset)
    final_dataset = Fixing_imbalancing_of_data(dataset)
    selected_features = Feature_selection(final_dataset)
    flag = model_training(final_dataset,selected_features)
    if flag:
        return jsonify({'Result':'Model Trained Successfully','Number of times':counter})
    else:
        return jsonify({'Result':'Model Training Unsuccessful'})
```

Comment: You should better save counter to an external file if you want to prevent it from resetting. It's highly possible that your app will be restarted at some point and counter will change to zero

Comment: Yeah, I've created a text file on google cloud storage and saving counter to it. Thanks

Comment: Great! can you accept my answer below please? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Create a txt file (let's name it 'counter.txt') and write '0' in it
Then add these lines in your flask /train route:

```
with open('counter.txt', 'r') as f:
    t=f.read()
with open('counter.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(int(t)+1))
```

This way you will keep counter in memory, even if your app restarts